# Powershell manual multithreading

Tags: multithreading, powershell

I am writing an application to reboot servers remotely, first through WMI and then through PowerCLI in PowerShell.  I am looking for a way to speed up the process, as there are a few thousand servers that need to be restarted.

I tried Jobs, but that didn't seem to speed up the process at all.  Is there a way to force PowerShell to multi-thread tasks like this?

So I'd like to just send out a WMI restart to all of the servers in a list using 3-4 threads, then as any failures come in I would like to start processing those through the VIC right away.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$my_jobs = Restart-Computer -ComputerName $my_computers -AsJob -Force -ThrottleLimit 50
```